# change the sum after the change in the select field

Tags: javascript

This is my first post after having come to the forum for years ;)

My problem is that if the "wybierz-diete" changes, the sum value does not change

HTML:

```
<select id="wybierz-diete">
    <option value="fit">Fit</option>
    <option value="sport">Sport</option>
    <option value="economy">Economy</option>
</select>

<div id="fit" class="fit wybranadieta">
    ilość kalori:
    <select id="ilosc-kalori1" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="1200">1200</option>
        <option value="1500">1500</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
    </select>

    jak długo?:
    <select name="a1" id="a1" onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="f_a1" class="f_a1">1 dzien</option>
        <option value="f_a20" class="f_a20">20 dni</option>
        <option value="f_a30" class="f_a30">30 dni</option>
        <option value="f_b1" class="f_b1">1 dzien</option>
        <option value="f_b20" class="f_b20">20 dni</option>
        <option value="f_b30" class="f_b30">30 dni</option>
        <option value="f_c1" class="f_c1">1 dzien</option>
        <option value="f_c20" class="f_c20">20 dni</option>
        <option value="f_c30" class="f_c30">30 dni</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var fit_a= new Array();
    fit_a["f_a1"]=42;
    fit_a["f_a20"]=800;
    fit_a["f_a30"]=1200;
    fit_a["f_b1"]=45;
    fit_a["f_b20"]=870;
    fit_a["f_b30"]=1300;
    fit_a["f_c1"]=48;
    fit_a["f_c20"]=940;
    fit_a["f_c30"]=1400;

function podliczAfit() {
    var podliczAfit=0;
    var theForm = document.forms["dieta"];
    var selecteda1 = theForm.elements["a1"];
    podliczAfit = fit_a[selecteda1.value];
    return podliczAfit;
}

function calculateTotal() {    
    var kosztDiety = podliczAfit();
    var divobj = document.getElementById('kosztCalosci');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Twoje zamówienie wyniesie: $"+kosztDiety;
}
```

I know that when I will have a solution, I will already have another problem. For example, how to manage when choosing the next diet, a sport, for which I have not written any code yet.

Comment: You don't have an `onchange` event handler set up for that one like you do for the other two.

Comment: I updated your question a bit. Please check that it correctly reflects what you wanted to say, as the English was quite hard to understand.

Comment: trincot - thank you, all is good, Scott Marcus -  <select id="ilosc-kalori1" onchange="calculateTotal()"> not change sum